# C# structure for If.. And If... And If

Tags: c#, io

I am using Visual Studio 2013 Express and I am new to Visual C#.  I am sure there is a better way to do what I am trying and I would appreciate any suggestions.

The code I'm trying to write evaluates a series of tests and sets a flag only if all tests = TRUE.  I'm currently using six nested if structures to get this done and, while it works, I'm looking for a cleaner, more professional solution.  Here's the sample (shortened to three levels for this post):

```
private const string sDrive = "D:\\";
private const string sFolder = "FTP\\";
private const string sDivFolder = "ABC";
private static bool bSanity = false;

private static void SanityCheck()
{
    if (Directory.Exists(sDrive))
    {
        if (Directory.Exists(sDrive + sFolder))
        {
            if (Directory.Exists(sDrive + sFolder + sDivFolder))
            {
                bSanity = true;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("FATAL: Div folder doesn't exist.");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("FATAL: Root folder doesn't exist.");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("FATAL: Disk drive doesn't exist.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main issue is whether you need to keep the same error reporting you have now.  In general, if that is required, I think this is simpler to handle by inverting the cases.  That will allow you to remove the nesting by using `if`/`else if`:

```
private static void SanityCheck()
{ 
    if (!Directory.Exists(sDrive))
    {
       Console.WriteLine("FATAL: Disk drive doesn't exist.");
    }
    else if (!Directory.Exists(Path.Combine(sDrive, sFolder))
    {
       Console.WriteLine("FATAL: Root folder doesn't exist.");
    }
    else if (!Directory.Exists(Path.Combine(sDrive, sFolder, sDivFolder))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("FATAL: Div folder doesn't exist.");
    }
    else
    {
        bSanity = true;
    }
}
```

If the detailed error reporting is not required, you can just check for the lowest level folder directly:

```
private static void SanityCheck()
{

    if (Directory.Exists(Path.Combine(sDrive, sFolder, sDivFolder))
         bSanity = true;
    else
        Console.WriteLine("FATAL: Drive or folder doesn't exist.");
}
```

Comment: Reed: It's true that there are simpler ways of achieving the end result by just checking for the final folder, but I was just using this as a (poor) example to help illustrate the question.  Your first solution using case inversion is what I wanted to learn.  Thanks!

Comment: @KenMorley Glad I could help - that's why I listed both options ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
if (Directory.Exists(sDrive) && Directory.Exists(sDrive + sFolder) && Directory.Exists(sDrive + sFolder + sDivFolder))
{
    bSanity = true;
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("FATAL: Disk drive doesn't exist.");
}
```

&& is an early exit operator.

Comment: This is called short-circuiting.

Comment: @ReedCopsey, you're 100% correct and I just realized that. Fantastic eye friend!

Comment: The message will not show you which part of `path` is incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

How about using a loop and an array?

```
// set path array
var paths = new[] { sDrive, sFolder, sDivFolder };

// use StringBuilder for faster string concatenation
var sb = new StringBuilder();

foreach (var p in paths)
{
    // append next part of the path
    sb.Append(p);

    // check if it exists
    if (!Directory.Exists(sb.ToString()))
    {
        // print info message and return from method, because path is incorrect
        Console.WriteLine("FATAL: \"{0}\" path doesn't exist.", sb.ToString());
        return;
    }
}

// we are here, so the whole path works and we can set bSanity to true
bSanity = true;
```

You can easily manipulate how deap the check is by changing array length. And it will print you exactly what part of the path is not correct.

Comment: You have the right idea, but `Path.Combine` is better than using a `StringBuilder`. Also your new edit goes a bit overboard with the commenting IMO. `// check if exists`? The code is self documenting.

Comment: @ZongZhengLi Yes, it is overcommented, I agree. But that's not the code I would use in real product. It's more like *learning source* and that's why I wrote that many comments.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't exactly the same behaviour as the original, but it *is* much simpler.

```
if (Directory.Exists(Path.Combine(sDrive, sFolder, sDivFolder))
    bSanity = true;
else
    Console.WriteLine("FATAL: Div folder doesn't exist.");
```

Comment: Ha yeah, that is probably smarter.

Comment: This is clean, but does have different behavior (in terms of errors) from the original.

Answer (score 0):

So one possible *cleaner* solution might be this:

```
private static List<Tuple<string, string>> _dir = new List<Tuple<string, string>>
{
    Tuple.Create(@"D:\", "FATAL: Disk drive doesn't exist."),
    Tuple.Create("FTP", "FATAL: Root folder doesn't exist."),
    Tuple.Create("ABC", "FATAL: Div folder doesn't exist."),
}

private static void SanityCheck()
{
    var path = string.Empty;
    foreach (var t in _dir)
    {
        path = Path.Combine(path, t.Item1);
        if (!Directory.Exists(path))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(t.Item2);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```